# c++ copy assignment : why it is not applicable to use it dealing with uninitiated object?

Tags: c++, initialization, copy

I am reading BJARNE STROUSTRUP's great book : Programming : Principles and Practices using C++ programming. I am reading the part in which he tries to show how to design a vector. However, one sentence caught me. (I can only tell you the location of this sentence in the whole book if you are also reading this book, which is unlikely, so I don't locate it here.)

> "We move an element to the new space by constructing a copy in uninitialized space and then destroying the original. We can’t use assignment because for types such as string, assignment assumes that the target area has been initialized."

To help you get the context, I provide some codes here:

```
template<typename T, typename A = allocator<T>> class my_vector {
          A alloc;             // use allocate to handle memory for elements
          // . . .
private : 
    T* elem;
    int sz;//short for size
    int space;//actually means capacity here.
};
```

He is trying to show how to implement `reserve()`. The implementation is here:

```
template<typename T, typename A>
void my_vector<T,A>::reserve(int newalloc)
{
          if (newalloc<=space) return;               // never decrease allocation
          T* p = alloc.allocate(newalloc);          // allocate new space
     /***/for (int i=0; i<sz; ++i) alloc.construct(&p[i],elem[i]);// copy!!! he means we can't use copy assignment operator here!
          for (int i=0; i<sz; ++i) alloc.destroy(&elem[i]);                 // destroy
          alloc.deallocate(elem,space);             // deallocate old space
          elem = p;
          space = newalloc;
}
```

He means that we can only copy construct the `elem` using `alloc.construct()` rather than using simple copy assignment such as `p[i] = elem[i]`. And the reason he gives is what I quoted above.

Assuming copy assignment is defined for the generic type T (maybe using Concepts), why copy assignment can't be used here still? He says

> "such as string, assignment assumes that the target area has been initialized".

However, I don't get it anyway. Can you help me to understand his gist? I think copy assignment works out fine even target is uninitiated, after all, the target is the one to be initiated.

Thanks!

Comment: The book says that `std::string`'s assignment operator assumes that the target is initialized. Don't you believe it, or did you misunderstand it? (Assignment is when you give a new value to a thing that already exists; it does not initialize anything.)

Comment: There are many undefined behaviors even in the construct-then-copy version according to the current standard. So maybe this question can be only answered in a "practical" way. You may get a standard-confirmed answer when [this paper](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p0593r2.html) is accepted.

Comment: @molbdnilo I get your point. You mean that constructors are the one to do the initialization thing, and assignment are used for assigning values to already constructed objects. But why can't we use one implementation of copy assignment that also does the "initialization", which means no longer assume that target is initiated? Maybe it's because of performance. But are there any other "inevitable" reasons so that we must assume target is initiated when implementing copy assignment? Or is it just a usage philosophy?

Comment: Try to implement assignment for a class that does any kind of resource management (like `string`s of `vector`s dynamic storage) and that doesn't require the target to be initialized. (Remember that you can't tell from looking at something whether it has been.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes copy assignment should assume that the target is initialized.
For example, `vector`. When assigning a `vector` to another `vector`, resources in assigned `vector` should be `delete`, and that inevitably assume that the target is initialized because we have to reference the member pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a class like

```
struct Foo
{
    int * data;
    int size
    Foo() : data(nullptr), size(0) {}
    Foo(const Foo& f) : data(new int[f.size]), size(f.size) 
    { 
        std::copy(f.data, f.data + f.size, data);
    }
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& f)
    {
        if (&f == this)
            return *this;
        else
        {
            if (size < f.size)
                //allocate new space
            // copy
        }
    }
};
```

Now, if we replace

```
for (int i=0; i<sz; ++i) alloc.construct(&p[i],elem[i]);
```

with

```
for (int i=0; i<sz; ++i) p[i] = elem[i];
```

This isn't going to work.  `p[i]` refers to a `Foo` that was  never constructed.  That means none if its members have been set which means when we do `if (size < f.size)` we are accessing an uninitialized variable and that is undefined behavior.

This is why we make a copy (or move in C++11 and above).  It guarantees the object is constructed and that the "right thing" happens.

Comment: Thanks! So that somewhat depends on the implementation of assign operator. To be more specific, whether the implementor assume the target is initiated or not. If implementor assume the target is not initiated when assign operator is called, that can be avoided. Sometimes assuming target is initiated can bring about some code optimization, just like the `if` statement in your code but sacrifice some "portability".  So we comes to the debate of philosophy that whether we should assume target is initiated when implementing copy assignment, or move assignment.

Comment: BTW, is there any case that we must assume target is initiated when implementing copy assignment? I mean, some "inevitable" cases. That's should be more convincing.

Answer (score 0):

Vector is too advanced. I'm pretty sure a few hundred pages precede this example. So, If you have read the book carefully, you must have noticed the difference between assignment and initialization(more formally construction). Construction is like building a garage, whereas assignment is like parking a car inside the garage. How are you supposed to put a car in an unbuilt garage?

```
T* p = alloc.allocate(newalloc);
```

That just allocates the space, no object has been constructed yet(There is no garage). Thus assignment is not applicable(wanna park your car at the edge of a hazard?). So the next step is to build the objects and the best choice is copy/move construction. It is possible to default construct(build empty garages) an then assign to the objects(park the cars),but it is more efficient to copy/move construct and in terms of template library development, less demanding too.
Remember that allocators behave differently than `new` in that the latter automatically constructs the object(s) immediately after allocation while the former separates the 2 phases.